# Disable all disk cache features in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, benchmarking, hard-drive-cache

I am doing benchmarking of several algorithms involving read/write to disk.

As Windows provides some **cache** features, sometimes I get results like these :

- first run of the algorithm : 200 seconds
- second run of the algorithm : 90 seconds
- third run of the algorithm : 87 seconds

After a reboot :

- first run of the algorithm : 202 seconds again

It is rather simple to disable write cache (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259716), but **how to totally disable disk read cache?**

Comment: This question gave a helpful solution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405868/how-to-invalidate-the-file-system-cache